# Rails 4 cookies issue in FireFox and Safari, but works in Chrome?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4

**Controller**

```
  def index
    if cookies.blank? || !(JSON.parse(cookies.signed[:affiliate])['expires'] > DateTime.now)
      cookies.signed[:affiliate] = JSON.generate(
        id: params[:affiliate],
        expires: 30.days.from_now
      )
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
  <%= JSON.parse(cookies.signed[:affiliate])['id'] || 'None' %>
```

**Question**
This work in Chrome but fails horribly in FireFox and Safari. No idea why... What's the problem?

FireFox/Safari error:

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution.. Tested in Chrome/FireFox/Safari.. Split the `cookies` setter into a separate method. Working grrrrreat! Enjoy...

**Controller:**

```
  def index
    if cookies.signed[:affiliate].blank?
      @aff = 'ms'
    else
      @aff = JSON.parse(cookies.signed[:affiliate])['id']
    end
  end

  def ref
    if cookies.signed[:affiliate].blank? ||
       JSON.parse(cookies.signed[:affiliate])['expires'] < DateTime.now

    cookies.signed[:affiliate] = JSON.generate(
      id: params[:affiliate],
      expires: 30.minutes.from_now
    )
    end

    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

**View:**

```
  <%= @aff %>
```

Answer (score 0):

cookies.signed[:affiliate] looks like it's returning nil, which JSON cannot parse.

Try

```
def index
  if cookies.blank? || 
     cookies.signed[:affiliate].blank? ||
     JSON.parse(cookies.signed[:affiliate])['expires'].blank? ||
     DateTime.parse((JSON.parse(cookies.signed[:affiliate])['expires']) < DateTime.now)
     #You'll probably need to parse dates before using them after parsing JSON.
    ...
```

All I can think is that some of your previous development has set the cookie on Chrome, but not the others.

Comment: Hey so thanks for your answer... Turns out cookies are a real pain in the ___ to test... Just so you know `DateTime.parse()` is not required and it actually break the code...